# WPF control binding to previous binding before DataTrigger overrides it

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have the following question : what do I need to add in the code below to tell my RadioButton to bind on "IsFacturation" boolean that is attached to datagrid item ? I use a DataTrigger which defines its own binding onto datagrid readonly state, so I need to "get back" in binding definition, probably by looking at appropriate parent. I think I have to play with RelativeSource...

I observe that when a datagrid item has IsFacturation boolean set to true, the radio button isn't checked as it should be.

DataGrid items are an observable collection of "Adresse" objects, which define an "IsFacturation" property.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="AddressGrid" SelectionUnit="Cell" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Adresses}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- Region Facturation -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Facturation" SortMemberPath="IsFacturation" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AddressGrid,Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <!-- Possibly create another contentcontrol which differentiates between errors -->
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Image Source="Resources/Images/Check-icon.png" Visibility="Visible"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AddressGrid,Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <RadioButton GroupName="grpRadioButtonFacturationAddresses" 
                                                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFacturation, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The goal of such code is to display an image when datagrid is readonly, and a radio button when it's not. I still have to work on image visibility (easy), but radio button state is directly linked to datagrid item property of my choice.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `"{Binding Path=IsFacturation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"` instead if you want the value to update immediately. What is the purpose of you using a `ContentControl` in your column? It does nothing except waste resources.

Comment: So I have unnecessary code to use my two data triggers? What would be the relevant code to achieve the same behavior? Thank you for pointing out this. Sorry, it doesn't work either with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, it's strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just answering your comment, not your question. One way that you could use `DataTrigger`s without a `ContentControl` is to move them to the actual controls:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Resources/Images/Check-icon.png" Visibility="Visible">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AddressGrid,Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <RadioButton GroupName="grpRadioButtonFacturationAddresses" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFacturation, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <RadioButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Setter Visibility="Visible" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AddressGrid,Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RadioButton.Style>
        </RadioButton>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I see that you set data triggers into controls styles, while our way was setting controls in styles data triggers. What's the best in terms of execution time and resource usage ? I believe our way may save resources, while yours may execute speedier?

Comment: I've just changed the `Hidden` values to `Collapsed` in my example as it's slightly more efficient. The main reason for moving the `DataTrigger`s to the control was because that's where they're supposed to be... think of `Trigger`s like this: *when something happens, a control will change its own value*. When you start trying to change properties outside the control that hosts the `Trigger`, you can run into problems... it *is* possible, but not advisable. Incidentally, why do you think that your method would save resources? You were using up extra resources for `ContentControl` in every row.